# initParams are not working in WebFilter annotation

Tags: spring-boot, web

I created a filter using following annotations in a java web project created by spring-boot:

```
@Order(2)
@Component
@WebFilter(
        filterName = "jwtFitler", 
        urlPatterns = "/*", 
        initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "excludedPaths", value = "login, hello") }
)
```

However, the initParams are not working, excludedPaths and excludedUrls are always null. Could anyone help tell me why?

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    private String[] excludedUrls;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        String excludedPaths = filterConfig.getInitParameter("excludedPaths");
        System.out.println("excludedPaths:" + excludedPaths);

        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(excludedPaths))
            excludedUrls = excludedPaths.split(",");

        System.out.println("excludedUrls:" + excludedUrls);
    }

    //......
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to your use of `@Component`, your Filter is being found as a plain Spring component. As a result, the `@WebFilter` configuration has no effect.

If you want Spring Boot to scan for Servlet components (`@WebFilter`, `@WebListener` and `@WebServlet`) you need to use `@ServletComponentScan`. Typically, that annotation is added to your main application class alongside `@SpringBootApplication`. With that in place, you should remove `@Component` from your Filter.

Comment: Thanks :), it works after removing the Compoent annotation and adding ServletComponentScan annotation. however, the Order annotation doesn't work then.

Comment: Indeed. If ordering is important, you’ll have to use a`FilterRegistrationBean` instead of `@ServletComponentScan` and `@WebFilter`.

Comment: I am now using FilterRegistrationBean and everything works as expected. Thanks for your help, Andy. :)